# Why I can run Laravel project on Windows, but not on Mac?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, mamp

I'm new to Mac Environment. My colleague recently gave me a Laravel project that I had to work on with a new cosmetic changes.

Like usual I get all the files and do the typical things like git the project, install composer, install npm, database setup, `.env` file setup and run the project.

I can open the project on the landing page. But what happened was, when I tried to sign in, I failed to enter the homepage. When I check the console it says: [View error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym8aV.png)

```
POST http://localhost/aplikasi-laravel/MY/user/login 500 (Internal Server Error) Jquery-3.1.1.min.js: 4

Request URL: http://localhost/aplikasi-laravel/MY/user/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

For your information, if I install and create a new Laravel project on this OS, it works. But I need to work on this project. So I have no choice.

My Project Specifications are as below.

> Laravel: Laravel Framework 5.4.36
>
> PHP: 7.1.28
>
> MySQL: 5.7.26

So what I'm doing is I install MAMP, downgrade to PHP 7.1.31 (only this php version is available), try running the project. Still failed. So I uninstalled it.

I tried using homebrew and XAMPP, and still failed.

My OS is Mac OS Catalina.

Because I wasting so may time setting up the environment on the mac, I'm try to use my PC with Windows 10 installed. So here's my setup.

> Platform: XAMPP
>
> PHP: 7.1.28

With the same code and setup, I was able to run smoothly without any errors on Windows 10. So I think it shouldn't be a code problem (maybe).

Since I need to work with the Mac OS environment, I want someone to help me to give an idea on ​​how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: find out what the 500 error is ... check the server log ... could be issue with case sensitivity

Comment: if its laravel 6 then you need php 7.2. Try to use docker instead of brew, it'll be way smoother

Comment: The one thing I can think of is the folder and file ownership on Mac is different than Windows OS. On Mac you need to provide the execution access to the exclusively and then it should be fine. Check the file and folder permissions.

Comment: try to turn debug ON in your .env file `APP_DEBUG=true` then run `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: yes and the ownership of course `sudo chmod 777 -R <your project>/storage`

Comment: @lagbox The error is: `[error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aplikasi-laravel/` .

Comment: @Shirker I try both solution. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: have you tried `php artisan serve`? it will run its own web server. if its working then you can configure your apache